# How to get CollectionViewCell in collectionViewLayout?

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

below is my code.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell : UniversalNewChatUsersCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "UniversalNewChatUsersCell", for: indexPath) as! UniversalNewChatUsersCell

        cell.lblUsername.text = self.arrSelectedUsersToChat.object(at: indexPath.row) as? String

        cell.layoutSubviews()
        return cell
    }
```

and i want to change cell width as per it's content and for that i used below method.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: 150.0, height: 44.0)
    }
```

currently i pass static width.
now i want is that i want to access cell in `collectionViewLayout` method so i can get cell label and based on this label i can calculate width of it. how can i do that?

Comment: You have the `indexPath` in that method. So you can guess the size of that label.

Comment: @Denny Can you able to get text using `indexPath.item` for a particular cell?

Answer (score 1):

You can get cell by calling cellForItem of collectionview. Write the code in sizeForItemAt method

```
if let collectionViewCell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? YourCollectionViewCell {
}
```

Comment: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: Please check your cell reuse identifier and make your your have current name of identifier which are written inside collection view data source method to duque your cell. Can you please post more code to understand  ?

Comment: You are forcing cast the cell using "as!". The "if let" expects an optional. It should be "as?"

Answer (score 0):

Do following in collectionViewLayout method:

```
if let myCell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? UniversalNewChatUsersCell             
    print(myCell)
}
```

Comment: this code never print myCell. it goes to always else statement